# Serializing a <SelectField /> for material-ui

Tags: material-ui

I noticed the `SelectField` for material-ui is composed of `divs` and `spans` and as a result when serializing the form, which includes a `SelectField`, the `SelectField` isn't serialized. Is there a way to serialize the `SelectField`?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your particular question, but I'm wondering if you could use an AJAX approach rather than forms?

Comment: @LarryMaccherone could you elaborate on what you're saying here?

Comment: A common (more common than forms nowadays?) way of getting data from the browser to the server is to make a call to an API endpoint using some library like JQuery or a number of other REST/AJAX/AJAJ libraries. It's a different paradigm but it's become very popular. Sometimes it's called Single Page Apps but there is no requirement that it only be a single page.